# i cant update my apt

Tags: repository

```
[sudo] password for aidin: 
Hit:1 https://ir.ubuntu.sindad.cloud/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Ign:2 https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com mantic InRelease   
Err:3 https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com mantic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.19.236.24 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: The error states: `Err:3 https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com mantic Release 404 Not Found [IP: 104.19.236.24 443]` which would happen when `apt` cannot find a repository there.  If you remove `https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com mantic` from your `apt` sources, does the update complete successfully?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the command you tried. Also tell us (in your question) what Linux distribution and version you're using. Finally, include your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any other files under `/etc/apt/sources.d`

Comment: `lsb-release ` would be helpful here too. As a side note, those look like mirrored repositories.  Seeing as I believe this is Ubuntu 23.10 - Matic Minotaur, I would try [resetting my sources list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501796/how-to-use-a-sources-list-generator) using the first answer, before going much further.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `mantic` codename. [Supported codenames for Ubuntu](https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/):

> The supported releases are:
>
> Jammy (22.04)
>
> Focal (20.04)
>
> Bionic (18.04)
>
> Xenial (16.04)

The `cloudflare-warp` package is available for LTS releases. the `lsb_release -cs` will print your Ubuntu codename. just change it to `jammy` :

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-warp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/ jammy main" | 
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflare-client.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cloudflare-warp
```

Comment: Might be worth clarifying where the OP can/cannot use mantic in their situation